# java - getting child class object in parent abstract class function

Tags: java, json, inheritance, reflection, jackson

I am trying to write an abstract class which will map the string values to the object member-variables and vice versa using ObjectMapper of jackson-databind. This abstract class will be extended by each pojo of json.

```
import java.io.IOException;    
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public abstract class JsonToString {

    public JsonToString toObject(String jsonString){

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            mapper.readValue(jsonString, this.getClass());//problem
            System.out.println("inside object function of jsontostring : "+this);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured in mapping jsonString received to object" + e);
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured in mapping jsonString received to object" + e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured in mapping jsonString received to object" + e);
        }
        return this;        
    }
    public String toString(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = new String();
        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            System.out.println("Trouble in mapping object to string in json class : "+this.getClass().getName());
        }
        return json;
    }   
}
```

this class will be extended by each json pojo.

So here I want to return the object of child class for which the mappings has been done. Can someone please help me get the object and return it.

I am calling this method in this manner :

```
ITAGResponseInfo response = new ITAGResponseInfo();
response = (ITAGResponseInfo)response.toObject(cOutput);
System.out.println("Printing from the itagresponseinfo object : "+response);
```

Here ITAGResponseInfo extends the JsonToString class.

Comment: What problem are you having? Invoking `getClass()` in the parent class should return the child class, unless you've actually got an instance of the parent class (which you can't, if it is abstract).

Comment: mapper.readValue returns the object of class type mapped to json string values. what I want is the current class members should get mapped to the values and I should not need to receive any return object. calling response.toObject(jsonString) should do everything and the object values mapped. is this possible ??

Comment: I'm sorry, that comment doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: what I am saying is : I have a json response as string. so , first i create the json pojo class object. then call the toObject function which will map the json string values to the current object(this).

Comment: OK, and what happens?

Comment: response object should get its member-variables initialized to the values given in json string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73142/discussion-between-andy-turner-and-furquan-ahmed).